# String value in li's value attribute using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have string value in `li`'s value attributes but it is giving me 0 when I am trying to get with jquery. Any Idea why? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37pAZ/)

```
$(function(){
alert($('li').attr('value'))    
})

<li value="CAD"></li>
```

Comment: Because the [value](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html#li.attrs.value) property is supposed to be an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In html value is a predefined attribute for li which can store only number. you can find it here. As it can be used to store number of the list.

```
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_li.asp
```

Answer (score 2):

For custom properties you could use [`$.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method, for sample:

```
alert($('li').data('value'));
```

and in your `html` use the prefix `data-`,

```
<li data-value="CAD"></li>
```

You also could use [`$.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method to set values in a data custom property, for sample:

```
$('li').data('value', '123');
```

Comment: actually this is using `$.fn.data()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data-` prefix.

http://jsfiddle.net/37pAZ/1/

```
$(function(){
alert($('li').attr('data-value'))    
})

<li data-value="CAD"></li>
```

Comment: Why not `$('li').data('value')`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try following..

Html:

```
<li data-value="CAD"></li>
```

JS:

```
alert($('li').data('value'));
```

Here is demo : http://jsfiddle.net/ed8ZL/

Answer (score 0):

try this one [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37pAZ/)

```
<li data-value="CAD"></li>




alert($('li').data('value'))
```